# How to change height of "progress line" in Progress Bar?

Tags: java, android

Can I change the height of "progress line" in *ProgressBar* in Android, so it's larger than the "background line" to achieve this effect?

[image: what I want to achieve!!!]

I have tried setting *size* on background and progress items on my custom **progressBarDrawable**, but doesn't seem to work.

```
<ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="50"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/xml_progress_bar_line"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
```

Here is the *xml_progress_bar_line.xml* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <size
                android:height="5dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size
                    android:height="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/green" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do it with add android:top & android:bottom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:top=2dp android:bottom=2dp>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="5dp"/>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/grey" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <size
                android:height="10dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/green" />
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `maxHeight` and `minHeight` to equal each other, then set the `layout_height`explicitly.

Also try using `@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`

You can also set vertical scale - `mProgressBar.setScaleY(3f);`

Here's an example I took from: https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/android-change-progressbar-height/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a quick and detailed answer Dayan, but it's not what I needed. I, actually ended up not using progress bar.

Comment: @hakobyanheghine why not?

Comment: @c-an it just wasn't looking the way I needed :) I posted the solution  a little down (here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44628118/1627952)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the progress bar at all!

I just used 2 lines in relative layout. Here is the corresponding code!

Here is the progress bar background line xml (*xml_custom_progress_bar_bg.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="@color/light_grey"/>

</shape>
```

Here is the progress bar "progress line" xml (*xml_custom_progress_bar_progress.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="@color/green"
        android:endColor="@color/green"/>

</shape>
```

And here is the progress bar container:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/xml_custom_progress_bar_bg"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/xml_custom_progress_bar_progress"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Then, I calculate the progress manually and set the width of "progress line" programmatically.**